# can't get struct in return

Tags: blockchain, contract-design, dapps, dapp-development, storage

I am trying to execute unit tests for a solidity smart contract:

I have:

```
mapping (bytes16=>Device) public Device_Table

struct Device
{
    bytes16 UUID;
    bytes16 hardware_UUID;
    string phone_Number;
    uint256 created_at;
}
```

I wrote a function that returns a Device struct but I get an error?

I am also facing a problem when a struct to a function

Comment: So `return (bytes16, bytes16, string, uint256)` instead.

Comment: In fact I want to have the total of an object since I have an other servcie that consumes the output of the smart contract and I can't change the all scripts

Comment: Then do `(bytes16 UUID, bytes16 hardware_UUID, string phone_Number, uint256 created_at) = yourFunc(...)` in this other service.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the snippet in a `pragma ... contract` envelope so it compiles as presented. Include the wording of the error message you want to be tracked down, to reduce guesswork.

This works, with a warning:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract StructError {
    
    mapping (bytes16=>Device) public Device_Table;

    struct Device {
        bytes16 UUID;
        bytes16 hardware_UUID;
        string phone_Number;
        uint256 created_at;
    }
}
```

Here it is in Remix so you can see it recall a mapped struct with `bytes16` index input.

[image]

The warning about high/infinite gas is due to the `string phone_number`. The string could be any length. Gas cost scales with the length, so it is high/infinite.

You can see the error disappears if that line is commented out.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract StructError {
    
    mapping (bytes16=>Device) public Device_Table;

    struct Device {
        bytes16 UUID;
        bytes16 hardware_UUID;
        // string phone_Number;
        uint256 created_at;
    }
}
```

You could consider using a `bytes32` or a fixed-sized `bytes` array to hold the phone number so its size is not unlimited. It is worth mentioning that a fixed size `bytes32` is probably cheaper than a variable size string because `string` uses a `uint256` to hold the length as well as bytes to hold the data. The cost difference will be most obvious in write operations.

> I wrote a function that returns a Device struct but I get an error?
>
> I am also facing a problem when a struct to a function

You cannot/do not send or receive `structs` in function signatures without using the experimental ABI, which you should not do for production. You may pass them around internally (as storage pointers) but not in `public`/`external` functions. Instead, break down the elements into simpler types. For example:

`function setDevice(bytes16 deviceId, bytes16 hardwareUUID, bytes32 phoneNumber) public ... {}`

Hope it helps.